# Eclipse OSGI not dealing with provider selection in MANIFEST

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, osgi

I have a few maven-artifacts that are not under my control and which I need to use in a Plugin project. 
These maven artifacts are packed into OSGI bundles with felix-bnd through the [org.reficio:p2-maven-plugin](https://github.com/reficio/p2-maven-plugin)

I have quite a few of these artifacts and they are partly interdependent. Now what I have are the two artifacts A and B. On the maven side of things, B depends on A and includes it in the artifact that is used as basis to generate the OSGi-Bundle.

A exports (and actually contains) the package `a.foo`. B depends on A, packs the jar into the artifact and the Bundle-Generation incorrectly marks B as exporting `a.foo` as well.

So as of now I have the following two MANIFEST.MF files, which are not under my control:

**A/MANIFEST.MF**:

```
Bundle-Symbolic-Name: com.acme.A
Bundle-Version: 2.0.0.[...]
Export-Package: a.foo
```

**B/MANIFEST.MF**:

```
Bundle-Symbolic-Name: com.acme.B
Bundle-Version: 2.0.0.[...]
Export-Package: a.foo,
 b, b.bar, [...]
```

I'm rather confident that the problem would not appear if B were to `Import-Package: a.foo` and declare the export with a `uses="com.acme.A"`. The problem would also not appear, if B would correctly not export `a.foo` at all.

So I have a bundle, which depends on things from both A and B. It's MANIFEST looks like this:

```
Bundle-Symbolic-Name: org.foo.product
Bundle-Version: 2.0.0
Import-Package: a.foo,
 b, b.foo, [...]
```

This means I have both the bundles A and B in my target platform. When I now check the eclipse "Target Platform State" window for `a.foo`, I can see that eclipse considers it to be provided by **B**. Using a class from `a.foo` results in a compilation error:

> Access Restriction: The type 'ModuleException' is not API (restriction on required library '[..]/com.acme.A_2.0.0.jar'

Ignoring that compilation error and executing the bundle results in a BundleException because the import `a.foo` can not be satisfied.

To remediate this, I tried to nail down A as the provider for `a.foo` by changing the Import-Package statement to:

```
a.foo;
  bundle-symbolic-name="com.acme.A";
  bundle-version="[2.0.0,3)",
```

According to the [OSGI 7.0 Specification 3.7.10](https://osgi.org/specification/osgi.core/7.0.0/framework.module.html#i2480178) this is a perfectly fine specification.

This does change the compilation error to an explicit missing requirement. Eclipse cannot locate the package `a.foo` with the restrictions imposed. It does also not fix the runtime error.
Eclipse suggests a quickfix to add an `Import-Package` statement for `a.foo`. 
When I let eclipse do that it simply drops the provider-matchers.

When I explicitly put the `com.acme.A` bundle on the classpath (as suggested by @howlger), the compilation error goes away. The runtime error is unfortunately not affected.

Why does the provider-selection restriction not work as per spec?
How can I get eclipse and OSGI to select the correct provider bundle?

Comment: I tried _Provider Selection_ with a simple Hello World OSGi application in Eclipse Photon (4.8.0) and it works as expected: `Import-Package: org.osgi.framework;bundle-symbolic-name=org.eclipse.osgi` compiles and can be executed, `Import-Package: org.osgi.framework;bundle-symbolic-name=non.existing` gives _The import org.osgi can not be resolved_ errors as expected. Also with a version constraint and the bundle symbolic names surrounded by quotes I cannot reproduce this issue.